# CSS pseudo before and after positioning

Tags: html, css

I have question is it possible to position pseudo element in this style without margining px; [image: pic]

```
div:after {
    /*I want to be in the middle*/
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    width: 15%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

div:before {
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 12px solid tomato;
    width: 7%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: can you tell a little more, seems unclear to me :)

Comment: Ok I want to one of psedo element in the middle

Comment: How about showing some code? All I see is a picture of a black polygon. What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: okay; you need relative on parent div and top : 50%; https://jsfiddle.net/6mew8ksv/3/

Comment: @BoltClock I have updated may be some clear...

Answer (score 1):

You need `position relative` on the parent element and :pseudos `100%` far form the opposite position

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: black
}
   
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  left: 100%;
  /*left: calc( 100% - 10px );*/
  transform: translateX( -10px );
  background: green
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

[like so](https://jsfiddle.net/6mew8ksv/3/)?

use `translate(x,y)`
Revised my answer thanks to @GCyrillus

Comment: without any margin px

Comment: How about padding? :P if not, I don't think you can.

Comment: translate(x,x) it is https://jsfiddle.net/6mew8ksv/3/

Comment: Right! how could I forget!